# Recovered partition reports 0 bytes of free space

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs

First of all, I am certain there is free space o the drive, and on Linux the free space shows up correctly.
So, here's what happened. I noticed that one of my hard drives still has windows boot and recovery partitions. I tried deleting those partitions and extending the existing one. When doing so, I'm not sure why or how, Windows changed the partition type from basic to dynamic.

So, as a result I had three "orange" partitions and all were named "D:". Now, I'm assuming the other 2 partitions were just mirroring the main one, and since they were tiny compared to the 3+TB size of D:, they immediately showed up as filled to the brim (0 bytes free space). There were no obvious methods to change it back, so in an effort to do so I deleted all 3 partitions. Eventually I recovered my partition using a third party tool (AOMEI), and the partition shows up as basic but it still reports free space as 0 bytes. But only on Windows, Linux still reports the free space correctly. The other 2 partitions are currently unallocated.

Backup is currently not an option, since it's a 4TB drive. How can I get Windows to report the free space correctly?

Comment: You deleted the windows boot and recovery partitions from within Windows? Why did you delete these partitions if you still wanted Windows to be installed?

Comment: This is not my system drive. Those were leftover partitions from a previous install on a different machine. The partition itself currently contains no OS. I use it for data storage only.